# How can i achieve below layout

Tags: ios, iphone

[image]

I have total six groups,in which each group shows by scrolling vertically.In each group there will be a picture,post,post image and comments based on that.There are cases in which there will be only post no image,no comments etc.I am trying to achieve this by dividing each group by cell.So please advice me.

Comment: Show us what you've tried first.

Comment: What kind of technique do you use? HTML5, nativ app, Images?

Comment: Based on iphone,uitable view listing